# Python Requests library sometimes fails to open site that a browser can open

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a Python project where I need to go through numerous sites and parse them.

I have noticed that in more than several instances, `requests` fails to correctly get the site content even though the site opens just fine in Chrome and FF. For instance, in my code:

```
def get_site_content(site):
    try :
        content = requests.get(site, allow_redirects = True)
        content = content.text
    except Exception as e:
        if DEBUG :
            print type(e)
            print e.args
            print e
        global errors
        errors += 1
        return ''

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    # parse, tokenize and filter the content of the site
    [...]
    return tokenized_content
```

Afterwards, I do a check to see if site content is `''`. If so, I know that an error has occurred and I print out that loading that site has failed.

In my log:

```
Progress: [=========-] 1.8% Failed to load site : http://www.mocospace.com
[...]
Progress: [=========-] 87.8% Failed to load site : http://www.hotchalk.com
Progress: [=========-] 93.2% Failed to load site : http://Hollywire.com
Progress: [=========-] 93.8% Failed to load site : http://www.Allplaybook.com
```

If I run the exact same code in the Python shell, however:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> content = requests.get("http://www.mocospace.com", allow_redirects=True)
>>> content
<Response [200]>
>>> content.text
u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC [...]
```

In instances where I get a 403, it's still not an exception - as it should be.

```
>>> content = requests.get("http://www.hotchalk.com", allow_redirects=True)
>>> content
<Response [403]>
>>> content.text
u'<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

The *only* way for the log to say that loading has failed is if an exception was raised the `get_site_content()` returned `''`:

```
# data is a list of all urls together with their category
for row in data:
    content = get_site_content(row['URL'])

    if content :
        classifier_data.append((content, row['Category']))
    else :
        print "Failed to load site : %s" % row['URL']
```

What could this behaviour possibly be caused by? If this was C, I'd be looking for something involving pointers and undefined behaviour, but I cannot seem to find anything that could cause anything similar here.

---

**Edit:**

Using the robotparser module, I tried checking for [one of the above sites'](http://www.mocospace.com/robots.txt) `robots.txt` files and noted that `User-agent: *` is set at the very top. I do not see any entries that would otherwise disallow me from accessing its index page, so could this have been caused by something else?

In Python shell:

```
>>> import robotparser
>>> rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
>>> rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
>>> rp.set_url("http://www.mocospace.com/robots.txt")
>>> rp.read()
>>> rp.can_fetch("*", "http://www.mocospace.com")
True
```

Comment: Sites are free to alter behaviour based on the contents of the request, and frequently they do. Your browser sends a different set of headers than `requests` does; the usual culprit is the `User-Agent` header but other headers such as `Referrer` and `Accept` are also quite often involved. This is *not a bug in `requests`*.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I did indeed come across something like that in a request to some Wikipedia entries. In that case, would I only need to provide an additional `(... , headers = 'User-Agent': 'SomeAgent 1.0')` field, or does it have to include everything else expected of a header as well?

Comment: The `headers` parameter is a dictionary; you can try `headers={'User-Agent': 'SomeAgent 1.0'}`, but take into account that sites filter on user agents to try and keep out unwanted robot spiders. Read the site `robots.txt` and honour the requested policy there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `requests` does not raise an exception when a server sends a response. If you want `requests` to raise an exception for 4xx or 5xx response codes, then you need to explicitly tell it to do so:

```
response = requests.get(site, allow_redirects = True)
response.raise_for_status()
content = response.text
```

or inspect the `response.status_code` attribute and alter your behaviour based on its value. Also see [*Response Status Codes*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) in the quickstart.

As for sites behaving differently when called with `requests`; remember that HTTP servers are essentially *black boxes*. With in the HTTP RFC, they are free to respond as they please. That includes filtering on headers and altering behaviour based on *everything* in the request, up to and including entirely random responses.

Your browser sends a different set of headers than `requests` does; the usual culprit is the `User-Agent` header but other headers such as `Referrer` and `Accept` are also quite often involved. This is *not a bug in `requests`*.

It depends on each specific site configuration how they'll behave. You can try setting additional headers such as `User-Agent` to try and spoof desktop browsers, but do take into account that not all sites welcome such behaviour. If you are spidering a site, try to honour their `/robots.txt` policy and *do not spider sites that request you do not*. If you want to automate this process, you could the  [`robotparser` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/robotparser.html) that comes with Python.

You can set additional headers with the `headers` argument to `requests.get()`:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'FooBar-Spider 1.0'}
response = requests.get(site, headers=headers)
```

but again, don't spoof browser user agent strings if a site is clearly asking you not to spider them.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. My wording up there was a little bad: I *expected* it not to raise an exception but instead give back a status code. I replied to your first comment above, and I think that is the crux of my issue. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look!

Comment: @user991710: I'm not sure what you mean by *does it have to include everything else expected of a header as well*. Headers are expected to be ASCII or Latin-1 encoded strings, with specific meanings assigned to specific headers named in the RFC standard. The `User-Agent` header doesn't have much meaning assigned; to spoof a desktop browser you'd need to copy what they send exactly. I cannot stress enough that you need to respect the remote server's wishes; they can always decide to block you altogether if you don't.

Comment: I see. In that case, is it considered acceptable behaviour to check a site's `/robots.txt` and simply skip requesting content if it is *not* the case that `User-agent: *`?

Comment: @user991710: you can use the `robotparser` library to parse the file and determine if you can continue requesting other urls on the site.

Comment: Excellent information. Thank you very much for the swift replies.

Comment: My apologies for bringing this question up again, but it seems that in some cases the result is the same regardless of the `User-Agent` header. I have included some more information in the original post, would you care to take a look?

Comment: @user991710: again, *it depends on the server*. You'll have to experiment. `Referer` (sic), `Accept`, cookies and any number of other parameters could be influential. It varies from server to server and depends on how determined the owners of a site are about keeping someone out. I cannot help you with each individual site you have problems with, not in this context.

Comment: Of course, I did not expect anything of the sort. Thank you; never having done anything of this sort, I didn't realize that the server had so much freedom in responding to a request.