# I can't get a html page with requests

Tags: python, timeout, python-requests, screen-scraping

I would like to get an html page and read the content. I use requests (python) and my code is very simple:

```
import requests    
url = "http://www.romatoday.it" 
r = requests.get(url)
print r.text
```

when I try to do this procedure I get ever: 
Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')
If I open the url in a browser all work well.

If I use requests with other url all is ok

I think is a "http://www.romatoday.it" particularity but I don't understand what is the problem. Can you help me please?

Comment: You have a typo in an url, comma instead of dot

Comment: Thanks @Abdulafaj. I don't know this kind of problem. Can you explain ? thaanks again

Comment: Thee problem isn't the comma (is a my edit mistake). The url without the comma doesn't work

Comment: Can you try traceroute or pathping (if you're on windows) to the URL?

Comment: I've done "ping www.romatoday.it" and all works.

Comment: "tracert www.romatody.it " is ok too

Comment: It's also possible the web server is blocking requests based on the user agent header which identifies the client application. Here's how to spoof it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606133/sending-user-agent-using-requests-library-in-python

Comment: Here's another directly relevant Q/A on this issue that might be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422956/python-requests-library-sometimes-fails-to-open-site-that-a-browser-can-open

Comment: How many times have you been hammering the server?

Comment: I think I have get the url 15, 20 times. And every time I get Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out')

Comment: Are you sleeping between requests? Also are you using a session or creating a new connection for each request?

Comment: "Are you sleeping between requests? "I don't understand sorry.

Comment: Ok lets digress, what version of requests are you using?

Comment: request versione is 2.7.0

Comment: Now I have upgrade requests (2.11.1) but I have the problem again.

Comment: Have you turned on debugging?

Comment: Yes I'm in Django enviroment. With the new requests version I get:  HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.romatoday.it', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /eventi/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xeca6d7ac>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

Comment: I create a new connection for each request

Comment: Could be a header setting problem?This is the headers in Chrome 
Server: BlackStone
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: DYNAMIC+ BlackStone (build: 40626; date: Sat, 06 Aug 2016 15:14:02 +0200; server: cn03-www1)
Vary: Cookie
ETag: W/"jTgH1uatCeiJCmWovJqQU5"
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2016 10:22:03 GMT
Expires: Tue, 06 Sep 2016 10:40:37 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=1114, post-check=1114, pre-check=1114
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: __bs=cn03-www1|V86Yz|V86Yz; path=/; HttpOnly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that the comma here

```
>> url = "http://www.romatoday,it"
```

should be a dot

```
>> url = "http://www.romatoday.it"
```

I tried that and it worked for me

Comment: Sorry is a my mistake. I have edit it. The url (without the comma) doesn't work again. Could be a requests module version problem?

Answer (score -1):

Hmm..Have you tried other packages, not 'requests'?

the code blow is same result as your code.

```
import urllib

url = "http://www.romatoday.it" 
r = urllib.urlopen(url)
print r.read()
```

[a picture that I captured after running your code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVBJa.png)

Comment: requests works for me so obviously it is not requests that is the issue, also this would be better as a comment as it does not answer the question.

Comment: With urlib is the same